# Adjust UIView inside UIScrollView MultiOrientation

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

In my app i receive a **image** dynamically.
After process the image i need to add some **views** on top of that image (after the user can drag this views).
To accomplish that, i put the image on **UIImageView** and add the views on that UIImageView.

According on its dimension i need to adjust the UImageview to fit the screen, **but maintain the original scale.**. The user can also make zoom.

The main problem appears when the user rotate the device. I need to adjust the UIImageView and it´s subviews correctly to maintain their relationship with the image.

For example in portrait:

[image]

And Lanscape:

[image]

My doubts:

1. Correctly adjust the UIImageview´s size, maintainig it´s original scale.
2. Adjust the subviews to maintain their relation position to the UIImageView.

Thanks in advance